# Execute a command upon startup

Tags: bash, mount, startup, cloud, startup-applications

### **The problem:**

I have some important files that I access regularly on OneDrive. So I have found a tool called `rclone` that allows me to mount a drive where all of my files would sync and I would have access to them. To mount both of my drives I use the command 
 `rclone --vfs-cache-mode writes mount 'Personal Onedrive': ~/'Personal - Onedrive'` for my personal OneDrive
 and 
`rclone --vfs-cache-mode writes mount 'Business Onedrive': ~/'Business - Onedrive'` for my business OneDrive

The problem is that I have to execute those commands every time I turn my computer on, and I was wondering if there was a way to get them to run automatically upon system boot.

### What I have tried:

- I have tried adding the commands to the Startup applications by adding these commands:
  `.sh -c "rclone --vfs-cache-mode writes mount 'Personal Onedrive': ~/'Personal - Onedrive'"`
  and
   `.sh -c "rclone --vfs-cache-mode writes mount 'Business Onedrive': ~/'Business - Onedrive'"`
   
  I have also tried directly just adding the bare commands to the Startup applications. As in 
   `rclone --vfs-cache-mode writes mount 'Personal Onedrive': ~/'Personal - Onedrive'`
  And
   `rclone --vfs-cache-mode writes mount 'Business Onedrive': ~/'Business - Onedrive'` 
   And none of them have worked so far
- I have also edited the /etc/rc.local file using the command `sudo nano /etc/rc.local` so now it looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
rclone --vfs-cache-mode writes mount 'Personal Onedrive': ~/'Personal - Onedrive'
rclone --vfs-cache-mode writes mount 'Business Onedrive': ~/'Business - Onedrive'
```

[![Screenshot of the document][1]][1]

And used the command `chmod +x /etc/rc.local` to set the file as executable which doesn't seem to have worked either.

Any amount of help would be much appreciated

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: To run a script *after login*  (appropriate for a user script on a desktop system), put the script in ~/,config/autostart directory. Remember to `chmod +x` the script so it is executable. Running a script before login is different.

Comment: @user535733 can you put a script there? I thought only .desktop launchers belonged there.

Comment: Should work with autostart. Edit your post and provide details on what exactly you tried and what exactly did not work.

Comment: @vanadium done! I have edited the "Startup applications" part with more detail

Comment: @user535733 isn't editing the /.config/autostart basically the same thing as adding the command to Startup applications?

Comment: @UBoiii they are indeed two different ways of accomplishing the same thing. One is Gnome-specific, one is not. Have you grepped /var/log/syslog for rclone error messages?

Comment: @user535733 this is the output of grep 

https://i.imgur.com/kdTewx3.png

Comment: @UBoiii Oops, I did not realize the graphical utility "Startup applications" is installed. Yes, it is the same.

Comment: In your startup command, there is a dot before "sh". That should not be there. Remove it and try again. If it does not work, (likely, because it did not with the direct command) try if delaying the command for a second helps: add "sleep 1 && " in front of the command (between the "" after "sh -c " obviously)

Comment: @vanadium adding a wait time before executing the command worked! thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Special thanks to @vanadium for providing me with the solution

I just needed to add a little wait time before executing the command. By adding those 2 lines to the Startup Applications
`sh -c "sleep 5 && rclone --vfs-cache-mode writes mount 'Personal Onedrive': ~/'Personal - Onedrive'"` 
and
`sh -c "sleep 5 && rclone --vfs-cache-mode writes mount 'Business Onedrive': ~/'Business - Onedrive'"`